# How to get file name for the logger log4j2 with sl4j

Tags: slf4j, log4j2

I got log4j2 accessed through sl4j. 
I want to save paths of some files where certain messages with parameters will be created.
I don't want to fix appender names and patterns and hardcode it into my code.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Another working for my app solution will be runtime configuration addition garanteing it will be used for certain class and no other config will be used or affected. This is subtopic I suppose.

Comment: I think it's not possible without using the classes of Log4J 2.